# How to import only sheets with specific text in the name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, import, importrange

I'm using this [script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95191/importrange-all-sheets/95202) but it takes all sheets of current spreadsheet. A bit modified script from original, but it doesn't achieve what I want:

```
function importallMain() {
  var id = 'some id';  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); //Managed to exclude first 7 from array because adds (;)
  var imports = ss.getSheets().splice(7).map(function(s) {
 if(['MasterBook', 'MasterClients', 'Rates', 'Listing', 'CreateDOC', 'Accounting' , 'Project'].indexOf(s.getName()) == -1) // Excluding by name
    return 'importrange("' + id + '", "' + s.getName() + '!A11:Y500")'; 
  });
  var formula = '=query({' + imports.join('; ') + '},"Select * where Col3 <> \'\' ")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
}
```

What I would like is that it would take sheets whose names contain `Ready`.

Comment: Please _don't_ add the solution to your question. If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark. If you've found your own solution, please write your own answer and accept that. Please take the site [tour] to get a better notion how the site works, and also the advice in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) of JavaScript to find the string "ready" in the name and only take those sheets. 
Like so:

```
function importallMain() {
  var id = 'some id';  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); //Managed to exclude first 7 from array because adds (;)
  var imports = ss.getSheets().splice(7).map(function(s) {
   var sheetName = s.getName()
 if(sheetName.match("Ready") != null) // Excluding sheet that dont have ready in their name! 
    return 'importrange("' + id + '", "' + s.getName() + '!A11:Y500")'; 
  });
  var formula = '=query({' + imports.join('; ') + '},"Select * where Col3 <> \'\' ")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! It now excludes sheets, but it adds trailing semicolons for excluded sheets like so: `=query({importrange("id", "ReadyDublicate!A11:Y500"); importrange("id", "ReadyDublicate1!A11:Y500"); ; ; },"Select * where Col3 <> '' ")`
Maybe you have an idea how to get rid of them?
Thanks!

Comment: Found [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) and helped solving the problem
This line takes care of empty array 
  imports = imports.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); // excludes empty array elements